# Python Tkinter button width and heigth

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter, trying to create a square botton but I can't.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
button1 = Button(text = "Cuadrado", height = 10, width = 10).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The widht and the height are the same valor, but the button that create with the code is a rectangle.
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of a button that has text but no image are in the number of characters (ie: height=10 means it should be 10 characters tall).

The average character in your font is almost certainly not a square -- fonts are typically taller than they are wide. Thus, 10 characters wide will likely be fewer pixels than 10 characters tall.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the characters is about 2.3 times greater than the width. So, to draw a square button, you can use proportions like this:

```
Button(width=2, height=1)
Button(width=9, height=4)
Button(width=19, height=8)
Button(width=37, height=16)
```